# C++ atomic fences and reordering

Tags: c++, multithreading, race-condition, memory-barriers, stdatomic

I have a question regarding the following code:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> shared_obj = std::make_shared<int>(222);
std::atomic<bool> flag = false;

...

THREAD 1

while (running.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
    if (std::shared_ptr<int> v = std::atomic_load(&shared_obj)) {
        flag.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
        do_work(v);
        v.reset();
        flag.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
    }
}

...

THREAD 2

std::atomic_exchange(&shared_obj, std::shared_ptr<int>{});
while (flag.exchange(true, std::memory_order_relaxed))
    ;
// at this point, it's guaranteed that the underlying object of shared_obj is deleted.
```

From my viewpoint

1. `atomic_thread_fence` in my code prevents reordering of operations across the fence.
2. After the thread 2 finishes the loop, the underlying object of `shared_obj` is guaranteed to be deleted.
3. `flag.exchange` is a RMW operation, meaning it will always operate on the latest value of `flag` regardless of the chosen `std::memory_order`.

Are these statements correct?

Comment: Looks like either SO did not acquire the question or you forgot to release it :)

Comment: Regarding the guarantee at the end, I think the safety depends on the actual operations performed here. The CAS using relaxed order, which makes me believe some operations might be reordered to before the loop... maybe?

Comment: @dyp I want to ensure that the first `flag.release(1, relaxed)` will not be reordered with the subsequent operations

Comment: Thread 1 performs the atomic_load from shared_obj, then thread 2 performs both exchanges. The result is that `shared_obj == nullptr` but the object still lives on in `v`. Does that break the guarantee?

Comment: Why not use `flag.store(true, release);`?

Comment: @dyp If I'm not mistaken, a fence works in both ways. For example, `do_work(v)` cannot be executed before `flag.release(1, relaxed)`. As for your scenario - yes, you are right. I think, this can be fixed by moving `flag.release(1, relaxed)` before `atomic_load`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Ah right, any writes in `do_work` could be reordered before the store to the flag. You do work on a local copy though, so not sure what kind of operations would have to be protected from reordering. To put it in @Yakk's words (which I hope to paraphrase well enough), any lock-free algorithm should be based on a proof. If no one does that work for you here, all we can do is try to come up with counterexamples. That doesn't prove the absence of bugs.